# Почему в адресе добавляется /home.php#...?

Tags: php, браузер

Когда заходишь на сайт в опере, в адресе добавляется `/home.php#/home.php#/home.php#`.

Есть сайт `http://yametal.net`, когда захожу на него в опере 11, в браузерной строке добавляет `/home.php#/home.php#/home.php#` и т.д. От чего такое может быть?

Comment: Это проблема не в обозревателе, а в коде. Код `index.php` в студию.

Comment: Ничего подобного не наблюдаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть и вирус, добавляющий текст в адресную строку, встречался с вирусом добавляющий строки и сходный код каждой страницы которую я посещал